# Deriving Fermat's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I had an exercise for homework for a class that said prove
$$(k+1)^p-k^p\equiv 1\pmod{p}$$
for all $k=0,1,....$
So I use the binomial formula to expand
$$1=1^p=(k+1-k)^p=((k+1)-k)^p$$
$$=(k+1)^p+\left(\sum_{m=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{m}(-1)^{m+1}(k+1)^{p-m}k^m\right)-k^p$$
But since $\binom{p}{m}=p\frac{(p-1)!}{(p-m)!m!)}\equiv 0\pmod{p}, (k+1)^p-k^p\equiv 1\pmod{p}.$

But the next task is to use this information to derive Fermat's theorem and I'm not sure now to get the expression in the form $a^{p-1}$.  Any hint would help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've shown that
$$
a^p-a\equiv0\pmod{p}\tag{1}
$$
for all $a$. Now, remember that since $p$ is prime, $p\mid ab\implies p\mid a\lor p\mid b$. Now, $(1)$ is
$$
a(a^{p-1}-1)\equiv0\pmod{p}\tag{2}
$$

Comment: does this reflect the change that I made to the answer?

Comment: wait, so the middle terms of the binomial expansion reflect equation (1) in your answer right? (you wrote "you've shown that..." so I'm assuming that (1) was proved in my solution above...)

Comment: @Iceman: You've shown that $(a+1)^p-a^p\equiv1\pmod{p}$ and since $0^p\equiv0\pmod{p}$, induction gives you $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Oh okay.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The intermediate step is to rewrite what you just proved as

$$(k+1)^p\equiv k^p+1\pmod p$$

and then use this to prove that $k^p\equiv k\pmod p$ for all $k$ by induction.  It's certainly true that $1^p\equiv1\pmod p$, so the previous result and the inductive hypothesis combine to show

$$\begin{align}
(k+1)^p&\equiv k^p+1\pmod p\\
&\equiv k+1\pmod p
\end{align}$$

so the result is true for all (positive) $k$ (hence all $k$, since you really only need it for $1\le k\le p$).

Once you have $k^p\equiv k\pmod p$ for all $k$, you can factor out a $k$ if it's nonzero, and get $k^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ for all $k\not\equiv0\pmod p$.

Comment: I had an inkling that was what he meant, but this really helps to see it better.  Thanks for your help, @BarryCipra!